# Remove regular expressions from a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

Is there a way to remove specific regex characters from a string?

For instance, this string:

```
"^/projects/.*/edit"
```

...without specific regex chars becomes:

```
"/projects//edit"
```

Comment: You want to remove chars like ".", "^" and "*" from your string ? What's the goal ?

Comment: This sounds like a XY problem: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=542341

Comment: Yes, any char which is interpret as a regex

Comment: `puts "^/projects/.*/edit".gsub(/[\^.*]/,'')`

Comment: Either you learn what is a regular expression (hint : your whole string can be interpreted as a regular expression) or you explain your real problem.

Comment: Yes, the entire string "^/projects/.*/edit" is a regex. I just need to clean it, to keep only no specific regexp characters

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
 "^/projects/.*/edit".gsub(/[^\/a-z0-9A-Z]/,"") # => "/projects//edit"
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have you try this :

```
 var input = @"^/projects/.*/edit";
 var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^a-zA-Z]", " ");
 output = Regex.Replace(output.Trim(), @"\s+", "-");
```

Comment: Are you really sure this is Ruby code?